# Why all accordion toggle together in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have accordion when i click on `+` button then all the accordion opening together what is wrong here?

My Code:-

```js
const questions = [
    {
        id:1,
        question: 'what is the react one',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
    {
        id:2,
        question: 'what is the react two',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
    {
        id:3,
        question: 'what is the react two',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
    {
        id:4,
        question: 'what is the react two',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
    {
        id:5,
        question: 'what is the react two',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
    {
        id:6,
        question: 'what is the react two',
        answer: 'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'
    },
];

const Accordion = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(questions);
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div style={{ padding: "50px" }}>
        <h2>Arrordion</h2>
        {data.map((curElem) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="main-heading">
                <p
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  onClick={() => setShow(!show)}
                >
                  +
                </p>
                <h3>{curElem.question}</h3>
              </div>
              {show && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Accordion/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Thank You!

Comment: I think there is only one accordion here and multiple `p` tags. Do you mean all your `p` tags are toggled together?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the state. When you click on any of the accordian, the state changes to true, and since you have used the same state on all accordians, all of those turn true and hence open.

The solution could be to define your state as an array:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState([])
```

and your function could be like this;

```
{data.map((curElem, i ) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="main-heading">
            <p
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={() => setShow(prevState => prevState[i] = !prevState[i])}
            >
              +
            </p>
            <h3>{curElem.question}</h3>
          </div>
          {show[i] && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are having only one flag `show` as state for all the Accordions that are there. That's why when you click on one `+` button, the state `show` is getting updated to `true` and as you have `{show && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}` all the answers are visible.

To fix the issue you might want to store the expanded accordion id as shown below.

```js
const questions = [{id:1,question:'what is the react one',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:2,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:3,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:4,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:5,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:6,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},];

const { useState, Fragment } = React;

const Accordion = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(questions);
  const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = useState(-1);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div style={{ padding: "50px" }}>
        <h2>Arrordion</h2>
        {data.map((curElem) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="main-heading">
                <p
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  onClick={() => setExpandedId(curElem.id)}
                >
                  +
                </p>
                <h3>{curElem.question}</h3>
              </div>
              {expandedId === curElem.id && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Accordion />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

If you want multiple accordions can be opened or expanded then instead of just storing the id of one item, we can have an array of `id`s and use that to identify whether that particular item is opened/expanded to show the answer. Below is the solution for the same.

```js
const questions = [{id:1,question:'what is the react one',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:2,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:3,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:4,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:5,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},{id:6,question:'what is the react two',answer:'react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components'},];

const { useState, Fragment } = React;

const Accordion = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(questions);
  const [expandedIds, setExpandedIds] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div style={{ padding: "50px" }}>
        <h2>Arrordion</h2>
        {data.map((curElem) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <div className="main-heading">
                <p
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  onClick={() => setExpandedIds(ids => [...ids, curElem.id])}
                >
                  +
                </p>
                <h3>{curElem.question}</h3>
              </div>
              {expandedIds.includes(curElem.id) && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Accordion />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: We can also have toggle functionality on click of the button so that any accordion will be expanded and collapsed accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The onClick event handler on every element in the accordion is updating the same state i.e, `show`. So on clicking any of the element all would open.

Also, since you are toggling the state for `show` using it's previous value use should consider using a callback to set the state as state updates are asynchronous.

`onClick={() => setShow(show => !show)}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are having a single state variable to rule them all. You want finer control and need your state variable which is an array to control each individual item.

You can do it using the following method:

1. An array state variable
2. the index param from `.map()`
3. Setting state by making a copy of array and updating the relevant index

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import React from "react";

    const questions = [
      {
        id: 1,
        question: "what is the react one",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        question: "what is the react two",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        question: "what is the react two",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        question: "what is the react two",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        question: "what is the react two",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        question: "what is the react two",
        answer:
          "react is a javascript library for building user interfaces for UI components"
      }
    ];

    export default function App() {
      const [data, setData] = React.useState(questions);
      const [show, setShow] = React.useState(new Array(data.length).fill(false));

      return (
        <>
          <div style={{ padding: "50px" }}>
            <h2>Arrordion</h2>
            {data.map((curElem,index) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div className="main-heading">
                    <p style={{ cursor: "pointer" }} onClick={() => setShow((show) => { 
                       let copyShow = [...show];
                       copyShow[index] = !copyShow[index];
                       return copyShow;
                    } )}>
                      +
                    </p>
                    <h3>{curElem.question}</h3>
                  </div>
                  {show[index] && <p> {curElem.answer}</p>}
                  <hr />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-elbakyan-mn19u?file=/src/App.js:0-1878)

Answer (score 0):

i think using an active index for showing detail will be good answer .

```js
onClick={() =>
          activeIndex === -1
              ? setActiveIndex(curElem.id)
              : setActiveIndex(-1)
}
```